# Problemas usando Postman para acceder a un endpoint protegido con @login_required

Tags: python, django, postman

Tengo una app sencilla que trata de un CRUD de personas, este CRUD esta protegido con @loguin_required de django, la app funciona correctamente en mi localhost, pero al momento de querer traer el GET desde Postman esta obviamente me pide que primero debo autenticarme para luego poder mostrar los datos que le pertenece al usuario autenticado, y aqui me quede... he configurado la autorizacion a basic auth ya que toda mi app esta basada en vista basada en funciones y he utilizado modulos de django como login, logout, authenticate, loguin required por lo que deberia ser asi, en header me genera bien el campo autorizacion, pero al momento de hacer el GET o POST me arroja un 200 pero no me redirecciona o no me deja entrar a la ruta directa que deberia devolver el listado de personas. Aclaro que mi app funciona correctamente a nivel logico en localhost!!! He tratado de quitar la seguridad de csrf token con csrfexcemt pero tambien me arroja un 200 pero no me deja ver desde POSTMAN la ruta que deberia listar los datos que le pertenecen al usuario autenticado!!! Saludos a todos los bross... Muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías agregar algo de código a tu pregunta?

Comment: Precisamente que necesitarias? Mi app funciona perfecto, pero por alguna razon que no veo "desde Postman".  al momento de configurar autorizaciones en basic auth proporcionando las credenciales correctas + la configuracion de cookies y token, no funciona, lo que me sirvio temporalmente es administrarle user y password desde body en formato texto